# Docker - Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID

Tags: docker, com, dockerfile

Software I am running uses COM class library. when running it inside docker I get this error:
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {632F4591-AA62-4219-8FB6-22BCF5F60090} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Is there any way I can make this work?

Regards

Comment: This is a very generic error that means the component cannot be found. Try this site first, there are hundreds of possible ways: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616630/sapbobscom-not-working

Comment: I know how to solve this on windows but have no Idea what to do in docker. On windows I have to install some exe which registers this COM class.

Comment: You have to do the same thing on Docker. Your Docker VM is going to be running an instance of Windows. You need to copy the exe to the docker VM and then register it there.

Comment: This exe does not have silent install option, only GUI based installation.