# Using winword or excel library in Visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, ms-word, office-interop

I need to programmatically access word and excel files in my dotNet 4.5 Code. I am using Visual Studio 2013. I have added a reference to the DLL `Microsoft Office 14.0 DLL` and used following line of code:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

However I get following error when trying to run the application:

> The type or namespace name 'Interop' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add Interop of MSword into your project. **Add reference->assemblies->Extensions** find for the interop you want to add and add it.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670940/what-is-the-interop-dll) is a little explanation about interop dll.